# on click view details of a particular user using redux and reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So I'm creating what is at it's core a very simple application, using React + Redux. There is a collection of list of people on the left side,  and I want to be able to list details of those and then when the user clicks on one o the right side.

```
                The Chat List component 



                import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
                import { Media } from 'reactstrap';
                import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
                import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
                import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
                import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
                import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
                import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
                import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar';
                import { InputGroup, InputGroupAddon, Input } from 'reactstrap';
                import update from 'react-addons-update';
                import { Scrollbars } from 'react-custom-scrollbars';
                import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
                import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
                import {connect} from 'react-redux';

                import {getTicketingList} from '../../../actions/TicketingActions';

                // api
                import api from 'Api';

                // intl messages
                import IntlMessages from 'Util/IntlMessages';

                import {ticketData} from './data';

                // rct section loader
                import RctSectionLoader from 'Components/RctSectionLoader/RctSectionLoader';

                class TicketList extends Component {

                  state = {
                    sectionReload: false,
                    newEmails: null,
                    openConfirmationAlert: false,
                    selectedDeletedEmail: null,
                    snackbar: false,
                    snackbarMessage: '',
                    replyTextBox: false,
                    selectedEmail: null,
                    viewEmailDialog: false,
                        addNewUserModal: false, // add new user form modal
                  }

                    componentDidMount = ()=>{
                        this.props.

                  // on delete email open confirmation
                  onDeleteEmail(email) {
                    this.setState({ openConfirmationAlert: true, selectedDeletedEmail: email });
                  }

                  // close confirmation dailog
                  handleCloseConfirmationAlert = () => {
                    this.setState({ openConfirmationAlert: false, viewEmailDialog: false });
                  }

                  // delete email if confirmation true
                  deleteEmail() {
                    this.setState({ openConfirmationAlert: false, sectionReload: true });
                    let emails = this.state.newEmails;
                    let deletedEmailIndex = emails.indexOf(this.state.selectedDeletedEmail);
                    emails.splice(deletedEmailIndex, 1);
                    let self = this;
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      self.setState({ sectionReload: false, newEmails: emails, snackbar: true, snackbarMessage: 'Ticket Deleted Successfully!' });
                    }, 1500);
                  }

                  // show reply text box
                  showReplyTextBox(email) {
                    let indexOfEmail = this.state.newEmails.indexOf(email);
                    this.setState({
                      newEmails: update(this.state.newEmails,
                        {
                          [indexOfEmail]: {
                            replyTextBox: { $set: true }
                          }
                        }
                      )
                    });
                  }

                  // reply email
                  replyEmail(email) {
                    let indexOfEmail = this.state.newEmails.indexOf(email);
                    this.setState({ sectionReload: true });
                    this.setState({
                      newEmails: update(this.state.newEmails,
                        {
                          [indexOfEmail]: {
                            replyTextBox: { $set: false }
                          }
                        }
                      )
                    });
                    let self = this;
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      self.setState({ sectionReload: false, snackbar: true, snackbarMessage: 'Reply Sent Successfully!' });
                    }, 1500);
                  }

                  /**
                   * On View Email
                   */
                  onViewEmal(email) {
                    this.setState({ selectedEmail: email, viewEmailDialog: true });
                  }

                  render() {
                    const { newEmails, selectedEmail, sectionReload } = this.state;
                    const {tickets} = this.props
                    console.log(tickets)

                    return (
                      <Fragment>
                        {sectionReload &&
                          <RctSectionLoader />
                        }
                        <Scrollbars className="rct-scroll" autoHeight autoHeightMin={100} autoHeightMax={400} autoHide>
                          <ul className="new-mail mb-0 list-unstyled">
                            {tickets.ticketData && tickets.ticketData.map((email, key) => (
                              <li key={key}>
                                <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                  <Media className="mb-10">
                                    {email.userdate.sender_avatar === '' ?
                                      <Avatar className="mr-15">{email.userdate.sender_name.charAt(0)}</Avatar>
                                      : <Media object src={email.userdate.sender_avatar} alt="profile pic" className="rounded-circle mr-15" width="40" height="40" />
                                    }
                                        <span className="ticketnumber">#{email.ticket_num}</span>
                                                  <span className="ticketnumber">{email.userdate.sender_name}</span>
                                  </Media>
                                  <span className="small align-self-center">{email.userdate.date_created}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                  <div className="text-justify">
                                    <p className="subject">{email.userdate.subject}</p>
                                    <p className="message">{email.userdate.message}</p>
                                    {email.replyTextBox &&
                                      <div className="task-foot d-flex justify-content-between">
                                        <InputGroup>
                                          <Input />
                                          <InputGroupAddon addonType="append">
                                            <Button variant="raised" color="primary" className="text-white" onClick={() => this.replyEmail(email)}>
                                              <IntlMessages id="button.reply" />
                                            </Button>
                                          </InputGroupAddon>
                                        </InputGroup>
                                      </div>
                                    }
                                  </div>
                                  <div className="hover-action text-right w-25 align-self">
                                    {/* <Button color="primary" className="text-white mr-5 mb-5" variant="fab" mini onClick={() => this.onViewEmal(email)}><i className="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i></Button> */}
                                    <Button className="btn-danger text-white mr-5 mb-5" variant="fab" mini onClick={() => this.onDeleteEmail(email)}><i className="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i></Button>
                                    {/* <Button className="btn-success text-white mr-5 mb-5" variant="fab" mini onClick={() => this.showReplyTextBox(email)}><i className="zmdi zmdi-mail-reply"></i></Button> */}
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </li>
                            ))}
                          </ul>
                        </Scrollbars>
                        <Dialog
                          open={this.state.openConfirmationAlert}
                          onClose={this.handleCloseConfirmationAlert}
                          aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
                          aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
                        >
                          <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{"Are You Sure Want To Delete?"}</DialogTitle>
                          <DialogContent>
                            <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
                              This will delete the email permanently from your emails.
                            </DialogContentText>
                          </DialogContent>
                          <DialogActions>
                            <Button variant="raised" className="btn-danger text-white" onClick={this.handleCloseConfirmationAlert}>
                              <IntlMessages id="button.cancel" />
                            </Button>
                            <Button variant="raised" color="primary" className="text-white" onClick={() => this.deleteEmail()}>
                              <IntlMessages id="button.delete" />
                            </Button>
                          </DialogActions>
                        </Dialog>
                        <Dialog
                          open={this.state.viewEmailDialog}
                          onClose={this.handleCloseConfirmationAlert}
                          aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
                          aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
                        >
                          <DialogContent>
                            {selectedEmail !== null &&
                              <div>
                                <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                  <Media className="mb-10">
                                    {selectedEmail.sender_avatar === '' ?
                                      <Avatar className="mr-15">{selectedEmail.sender_name.charAt(0)}</Avatar>
                                      : <Media object src={selectedEmail.sender_avatar} alt="User Profile 1" className="rounded-circle mr-15" width="40" height="40" />
                                    }
                                    <Media body>
                                      <h5 className="m-0 pt-5 fs-14">{selectedEmail.sender_name}</h5>
                                      <span className="fs-12 align-self-center">{selectedEmail.from}</span>
                                    </Media>
                                  </Media>
                                  <span className="small align-self-center">19 Mar 2017</span>
                                </div>
                                <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                  <div className="text-justify">
                                    <p className="subject">{selectedEmail.subject}</p>
                                    <p className="message">{selectedEmail.message}</p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            }
                          </DialogContent>
                        </Dialog>
                        <Snackbar
                          anchorOrigin={{
                            vertical: 'top',
                            horizontal: 'center',
                          }}
                          open={this.state.snackbar}
                          onClose={() => this.setState({ snackbar: false })}
                          autoHideDuration={2000}
                          snackbarcontentprops={{
                            'aria-describedby': 'message-id',
                          }}
                          message={<span id="message-id">{this.state.snackbarMessage}</span>}
                        />
                      </Fragment>
                    );
                  }
                }

                const mapStateToProps = (store) => {
                  return {
                  tickets : store.tickets
                }
                };

                export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getTicketingList})(TicketList);



            The Right side component

            import React, { Component } from 'react'
            import './style.css';

            import { Avatar } from '@material-ui/core';
            import {connect} from 'react-redux';

            import {ticketData} from './data';
            import { Input} from 'reactstrap';
            import {Button} from '@material-ui/core';

            import {getTicketingList} from '../../../actions/TicketingActions';

            // intl messages
            import IntlMessages from 'Util/IntlMessages';

            class Preview extends React.Component {


                componentDidMount = ()=>{
                    this.props.getTicketingList()
              }

                render() {
                const {tickets} = this.props
                    console.log(tickets)
                    return (
                    <div>
                      {tickets.ticketData.map((data, key) => (
                        <div className="lazy-up">
                          <div className="d-flex justify-content-inline headline">
                             <Avatar className="pre_avatar">{data.sender_avatar}</Avatar>
                             <span className="pre_span">#{data.ticket_num}</span>
                          </div>
                          <div className="card pt-30 mb-20 textspace">
                            <h3 className="text-pink d-block mb-5 headtxt">{data.subject}</h3>
                              <p className="fs-14 mb-10">{data.message}</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                    );
                }
            }


            const mapStateToProps = (store) => {
              return {
              tickets : store.tickets
            }
            };

            export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getTicketingList})(Preview);




        // action 

        import {
            Ticketing_List
        } from 'Actions/types';

        import {ticketData} from '../routes/ticketing/ticket/data';

        export const getTicketingList = () => {
            return (dispatch) =>{
                dispatch({ 
                           type: Ticketing_List,
                           payload: ticketData
                        });
            }
        }

        export const onSelectUser = (user) => {
            return {
                type: ON_SELECT_USER,
                payload: ticketData
            };
        };
        import {
            Ticketing_List
        } from 'Actions/types';

        import {ticketData} from '../routes/ticketing/ticket/data';

        export const getTicketingList = () => {
            return (dispatch) =>{
                dispatch({ 
                           type: Ticketing_List,
                           payload: ticketData
                        });
            }
        }

    //Reducer

    import {
        Ticketing_List,
        ON_SELECT_USER,
    } from 'Actions/types';

    const INIT_STATE = {
        ticketData:[]
    };

    export default (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {

            case Ticketing_List:
                console.log("Ticketing_List")
                return { ...state, ticketData: action.payload }

            default: return { ...state };
        }
    }
```

how i can select a user from the list and view details using redux

the index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './style.css';

import RctCollapsibleCard from 'Components/RctCollapsibleCard/RctCollapsibleCard';
import Preview from './preview';
import TicketList from './ticketList';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import {
    Modal,
    ModalHeader,
    ModalBody,
    ModalFooter,
} from 'reactstrap';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';

import AddNewUserForm from './addNewUser';


class Ticket extends React.Component {
    state = {
        all: false,
        users: null, // initial user data
        selectedUser: null, // selected user to perform operations
        loading: false, // loading activity
        addNewUserModal: false, // add new user form modal
        addNewUserDetail: {
            id: '',
            name: '',
            avatar: '',
            dateCreated: 'Just Now',
            checked: false
        },
        openViewUserDialog: false, // view user dialog box
        editUser: null,
        allSelected: false,
        selectedUsers: 0,
        userclicked:true,
    }

    /**
     * Open Add New User Modal
     */
    opnAddNewUserModal() {
        this.setState({ addNewUserModal: true });
    }


    /**
     * On Change Add New User Details
     */
    onChangeAddNewUserDetails(key, value) {
        this.setState({
            addNewUserDetail: {
                ...this.state.addNewUserDetail,
                [key]: value
            }
        });
    }

        /**
     * Add New User
     */
    addNewUser() {
        const { name, emailAddress } = this.state.addNewUserDetail;
        if (name !== '' && emailAddress !== '') {
            let users = this.state.users;
            let newUser = {
                ...this.state.addNewUserDetail,
                id: new Date().getTime()
            }
            users.push(newUser);
            this.setState({ addNewUserModal: false, loading: true });
            let self = this;
            setTimeout(() => {
                self.setState({ loading: false, users });
                NotificationManager.success('User Created!');
            }, 2000);
        }
    }


    /**
     * On Add & Update User Modal Close
     */
    onAddUpdateUserModalClose() {
        this.setState({ addNewUserModal: false, editUser: null })
    }

    render() {
        const { users, loading, selectedUser, editUser, allSelected, selectedUsers } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 w-xs-full">
                <div className="row">
                            <TicketList />
                </div>

                <div className="col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-8 preview_block">
                            <Preview />
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Ticket;
```

[image: The ui for the same is here]

I have a chatlist component on the left side and a component to preview the messages on the right side of the page . on clicking the left side i want to view the details.

Comment: Does the API call to see the ticket list contain all information of a specific ticket which you want to show on the right-hand side when clicking on it?

Comment: Please shorten the code examples to be more concise - it's extremely difficult to follow when it's that long

Comment: @Ismailp yes sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you case I would do something like this:

1) Create an action `chooseTicket` and then trigger that method when pressing on the list item. See below:

```
// TicketList component

<li key={key} onClick={ () => this.props.chooseTicket(email.id) }>

  ...

</li>
```

2) Add a new state variable in your reducer called `chosenTicket` and populate that by filtering out the correct item from your data array by using the `email.id` passed on from the action to the reducer.

3) Introduce `chosenTicket` in your `Preview` component, see example below:

```
// Preview component
...

render() {
  const { chosenTicket } = this.props;
  return (
    // Use the ticket data and visualize the preview
  );
}

...
```

With that said I would not recommend that you structure your code like that. There are better ways of doing this. For example divide the components into separate files.

I aslo feel it would beneficial to fetch the correct ticket from the API when populating the detail view. That would make it possible to have URLs for each ticket if one would like to share them.

Anyways, I would strongly recommend that you restructure your app to make it more maintainable and readable.